# Create new columns based on group by with Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I've got a scenario where I have to take the results from a group by and create a new columns.

For example, say I have this data:

```
| Tool         | Category   | Price      |
| Hammer       | Hand Tool  | 25.00      |
| Drill        | Power Tool | 56.33      |
| Screw Driver | Hand Tool  | 4.99       |
```

My output should look like:

```
| Tool         | Hand Tool | Power Tool |
| Hammer       | 25.00     | NULL       |
| Drill        | NULL      | 56.33      |
| Screw Driver | 4.99      | NULL       |
```

I'm not sure how to get this output. I'm trying something like the snippet below but it blows up with `column is not iterable`.

```
def get_tool_info():
    return tool_table.groupBy('Category').pivot('Price', 'Category')
```

What is the best way to dynamically generate these new columns and assign the price values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = StructType([StructField("Tool", StringType()), StructField("Category", StringType()), StructField("Price", FloatType())])
data = [["Hammer", "Hand Tool", 25.00], ["Drill", "Power Tool", 56.33], ["Screw Driver", "Hand Tool", 4.99]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.groupby("Tool").pivot("Category").agg(F.first("Price")).show()
```

Output :

```
+------------+---------+----------+
|        Tool|Hand Tool|Power Tool|
+------------+---------+----------+
|       Drill|     null|     56.33|
|Screw Driver|     4.99|      null|
|      Hammer|     25.0|      null|
+------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks a bunch, this is helpful. How do I prevent the groupby from dropping additional columns off? Say I had 5 columns vs just the 3.

Comment: I would just join afterwards the additional columns from the input data with the pivot data using the groupBy key.

Comment: Ok, that's the route I was taking. Wasn't sure if there was a slicker way of doing it. Appreciate all the help.